# Slide show program, event processing

Tags: python, tkinter

I need the images to change if the cursor is inside the window without moving, but I managed to make the image changes only if the cursor is moving inside the window, how can I change the code?

```py
from itertools import cycle
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import glob

image_files = glob.glob("*.jpg")
root = tk.Toplevel()
root.geometry("1600x900")
pictures = cycle((ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image), image) for image in image_files)                              
picture_display = tk.Label(root)
picture_display.pack()
def show_slides(event):           
    img_object, img_name = next(pictures)
    root.after(500, picture_display.config(image=img_object))  
root.bind("<Motion>", show_slides)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but have you tried using a tkinter loop?

Comment: You should use `<Enter>` with a tkinter loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate cursor position in loop and show image if it's located within tkinter window:

```
import glob
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from itertools import cycle

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('900x600')
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.lbl.pack()
        files = glob.glob('*.jpg')
        self.images = cycle((ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f), f) for f in files)
        self.show()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show(self):
        abs_coord_x = self.root.winfo_pointerx() - self.root.winfo_rootx()
        abs_coord_y = self.root.winfo_pointery() - self.root.winfo_rooty()
        if 0 <= abs_coord_x <= self.root.winfo_width() and 0 <= abs_coord_y <= self.root.winfo_height():
            img_object, img_name = next(self.images)
            self.lbl.config(image=img_object)
        self.root.after(1000, self.show)

App()
```

Comment: You can just use `root.bind("<Enter>")` and `root.bind("Leave")` with the help of a variable (that can be a Boolean flag). It is much simpler than calculating all of those positions. Edit: posted an answer with my suggestion implemented

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events and use a flag to control the call, followed by using the `after` method to loop the function.

```py
def show_slides(event=None):    
    global change_slide
    img_object, img_name = next(pictures)
    picture_display.config(image=img_object)
    change_slide=root.after(500,show_slides)  

def stop_slides(event):
    root.after_cancel(change_slide)

root.bind("<Enter>", show_slides)
root.bind("<Leave>", stop_slides)
```

**UPDATE**

Using a flag might cause multiple calls being scheduled it the events happen during the `500ms` delay, you can use `after_cancel` to terminate it.

Comment: But once `root.after()` has started, wont it just go on even if the flag says `False` and if flag is `True` twice, then wont two `after()` get run simultaneously?

Comment: @CoolCloud "*wont it just go on even if the flag says False*" I don't think so. But the flag staying true and multiple calls is possible, if the leave and enter within the `500ms` delay, I'll try and update in a bit

Comment: I actually think so, because once `root.after()` is scheduled for the `mainloop`, there is no other code that marks this event complete in the event loop and hence it keeps repeating itself. Maybe use `root.after_cancel()` once the user leaves the window or something.

Comment: @CoolCloud When the cursor leaves root, the flag would become `False` and prevent further scheduling, but if the flag stayed true (leave + enter within 500ms) then a new call cycle can be generated. The loop would definitely stop when you move out though because when flag is `False` all the cycles (even if multiple) would stop.

Comment: I always thought once the `after` call begins, the function is inside a loop, which wont be stopped unless you use `after_cancel` or exit the window. The flags seems incorrect to me. Or maybe you are correct here.

Comment: @CoolCloud Why don't you give it a try, you would understand the concept better. It doesn't work the way you are explaining. The `after` schedules the call to the given function which will be some time after the given time, if `after` is not called a new call will not get scheduled and the loop breaks.

Comment: Yea now it does makes sense, because you used `if` before. Thanks !